# Scroll ScrollView to top on content change, without glitching (React Native)

Tags: react-native, uiscrollview, react-native-ios

I have a `ScrollView` component (in React Native [iOS]) that is vertically-paged and populated with full-height images.

The result is a vertically-swipable 'gallery' of images that I *only want a user to be able to scroll past* ***once.***

When `onMomentumScrollEnd` is triggered, I delete the top-most image, and reset the scroll offset to zero. However, due to the state-change of the image content, the `scrollTo` call does not sync and results in visual glitching (i.e. the topmost image flashes as it is deleted). I've tried putting my `scrollTo` call after a state-change, to no avail.

I also tried it in the `onContentSizeChange` trigger, such as:

```
//...<ScrollView> props:
onContentSizeChange={(contentWidth, contentHeight)=>{
  this.photoScroll.scrollTo({x: 0, y: 0, animated: false});
}}
```

**Is there any way to 'sync' a `ScrollView`'s content adjustment with a `scrollTo({x: 0, y: 0, animated: false})` call?**

**Note:** I am using `create-react-native-app` and would really rather not have to eject — as a former iOS dev, I am aware there are libraries out there that can handle this kind of behaviour, but I was hoping to achieve this with vanilla-React somehow.

**Note 2:** Principally interested in iOS implementations for now — Android is a bonus.

Code Appendix:

**Scroll View Component:**

```
  <ScrollView
    ref={(ref) => this.photoScroll = ref}
    pagingEnabled
    style={{
      flex: 1,
    }}
    onScroll={this.onScroll}
    scrollEventThrottle={16}
    scrollEnabled={this.scrollEnabled}
    pinchGestureEnabled={false}
    onMomentumScrollBegin={this.onMomentumScroll}
    onMomentumScrollEnd={this.offMomentumScroll}
    onContentSizeChange={(contentWidth, contentHeight)=>{
      this.photoScroll.scrollTo({x: 0, y: 0, animated: false});
    }}
  >
    {/* Array of image source-views, stored in State */}
    {demoImages}
  </ScrollView>
```

**Class Method for removing image data:**

```
  offMomentumScroll = (event) => { // onMomentumScrollEnd
    this.isScrolling = false; 
    this.shouldCancelScroll = false; // used to block touches
    this.recalibratePhotos();
  }

  recalibratePhotos = () => {
    const { height, width } = Dimensions.get('window');
    const { scrollOffset } = this;
    const numberToDelete = scrollOffset / height;

    let photoData = this.state.photoData.slice();
    photoData.splice(0, numberToDelete);

    this.setState({
      photoData,
    }, () => {
      this.scrollEnabled = true; // used to block extra touches
      // onScroll has also appeared here — still glitches
    });

  }
```